# How to capture file names and check for date part in the filename in Unix code?

Tags: linux, unix, filenames

I am a newbie to linux and I have a requirement where I need to capture the file names, check the date in the file names and proceed and load the data from all the files only if all the file names have the same date in them. Lets say, I have few files

```
X_US_20130420.CSV
X_CA_20130420.CSV
X_PH_20130420.CSV
X_NS_20130420.CSV
```

I need to check if all the files have the same date (20130420 here) and then use that date as a parameter in my next job. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to go about this, but one way would be to loop through all the files, parse out the dates, and see if any date doesn't match the others.  I'm not going to deprive you of the privilege of figuring out the bulk of the work, but the date parsing can be done like so:

If you have bash:

```
file=X_US_20130420.CSV
myDate=${file##*([A-Z_])}
myDate=${myDate%.CSV}

# myDate is now 20130420
```

If you don't have bash:

```
file=X_US_20130420.CSV
myDate="$(echo $file | sed 's:^[A-Z_]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{8\}\).CSV/\1/')"

# myDate is now 20130420
```